# Programmatically setting key value pairs for ValueMap widget of QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Using QGIS 2.6 and Python 2.7 on Windows 7, I am trying to programmatically insert key value pairs into a ValueMap widget via a csv file. Issue is that some of the values are properly inserted and formatted, while some are not.

This csv value is formatted like so:

```
            ;                                                            
20          ;              20
25          ;              25
32          ;              32
40          ;              40
50          ;              50
60          ;              60
63          ;              63
75          ;              75
80          ;              80
90          ;              90
100         ;              100
110         ;              110
125         ;              125
140         ;              140
150         ;              150
160         ;              160
200         ;              200
225         ;              225
250         ;              250
300         ;              300
315         ;              315
350         ;              350
400         ;              400
500         ;              500
1/4''       ;              1/4''
3/8''       ;              3/8''
1/2''       ;              1/2''
3/4''       ;              3/4''
1''         ;              1''
1'' 1/4     ;              1'' 1/4
1'' 1/2     ;              1'' 1/2
2''         ;              2''
2'' 1/4     ;              2'' 1/4
2'' 1/2     ;              2'' 1/2
3''         ;              3''
3'' 1/2     ;              3'' 1/2
4''         ;              4''
5''         ;              5''
6''         ;              6''
```

I then created a dictionary from these values, programmatically set the widget, and configured the widget using this code:

```
resLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
with open('mycsv.csv') as f:
    f.readline()
    diamResDict = dict(csv.reader(f, delimiter=';'))
diamidx = resLayer.fieldNameIndex('Diametre')
resLayer.setEditorWidgetV2(diamidx, 'ValueMap')
resLayer.setEditorWidgetV2Config(diamidx, diamResDict)
```

The dictionary prints this:

```
{'140\t': '\t140', '250\t': '\t250', '50\t': '\t50', '\t': '\t\t\t\t', "1'' 1/4\t": "\t1'' 1/4", '150\t': '\t150', '40\t': '\t40', '125\t': '\t125', '400\t': '\t400', "3/4''\t": "\t3/4''", "1'' 1/2\t": "\t1'' 1/2", "3'' 1/2\t": "\t3'' 1/2", '25\t': '\t25', '100\t': '\t100', "1/2''\t": "\t1/2''", '300\t': '\t300', "4''\t": "\t4''", "6''\t": "\t6''", '60\t': '\t60', "5''\t": "\t5''", '80\t': '\t80', '32\t': '\t32', '225\t': '\t225', '200\t': '\t200', '110\t': '\t110', '160\t': '\t160', '350\t': '\t350', "1/4''\t": "\t1/4''", "3''\t": "\t3''", '90\t': '\t90', '500\t': '\t500', "2''\t": "\t2''", "1''\t": "\t1''", '315\t': '\t315', "3/8''\t": "\t3/8''", "2'' 1/2\t": "\t2'' 1/2", '20\t': '\t20', '63\t': '\t63', '75\t': '\t75', "2'' 1/4\t": "\t2'' 1/4"}
```

The result is this:

[image]

It's the apostrophes instead of keys that is causing me trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove whitespace, tab (\t) etc from the dictionary with something like:

```
new_dict = {k:v.strip() for k, v in diamResDict.iteritems()}
```

and then passing the new dict to `setEditorWidgetV2Config(diamidx, new_dict)`